# Make ZXing scanner scan only QR code on Android xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, qr-code, zxing

I`ve faced with problem of zxing scanner on Android in xamarin.forms. 
When I set only

```
ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE
```

to possible formats of scanning, it scans everithing it can scan.

On iOS I have no problems with that, it works like a charm.

Some suggestions?

Comment: You mean when you set format to `QR_CODE`, it will also recognize other code like barcode?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT exactly

Comment: If you think it's an issue of zxing package, you can submit it to the package source on Github.